# can c# application run without any constructor

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I've been asked this question and when trying search about it I found that the constructor is used to initiate a newly created object. Now what if our application doesn't contain any constructor.

In other terms, how is the main class initiated or instantiated.

Comment: If you only use static methods, you don't need a constructor. The `Main()` method is always static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't define a constructor method yourself, then .NET will create a default parameterless constructor for you:

> If you don't provide a constructor for your class, **C# creates one by default** [...]

Source & more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Notes:

- A Console app runs using `static` methods only, and therefore does not use a constructor, even if you provide one.
- There are also *static constructors*, which you can use to do initialization that will benefit the *static* properties and methods of the class. If there is one then the Framework will execute it as soon as (just before) you try to run any other code inside the class.